# Loop through string and style individual letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the title "INTRO TO GRID", and I want to individually style the letters in the string "GRID". I know I could do this with CSS, but I want to try with JS. I am having difficulty figuring out how to attach .css() to the individual letters. I have attached my code for reference. Thanks in advance!

```
var header = $("#header").text();

var grid = header.substring(9, header.length);

var chars = grid.split(""); 

for(var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    console.log(chars[i]);
}

console.log(chars);
```

With the help previous commenters, here is the solution to my problem.

```
var header = $("#header");

var chars = header.text().split("");

var headerSpans = chars.map(function(char){
    return $('<span>' + char + '</span>');
});

$(header).html(headerSpans);

 for(var i=9; i <= headerSpans.length; i++){
    headerSpans[i].css({
        "margin" : "20px",
        "background-color" : "red"
    });
 }
```

Comment: _I am having difficulty figuring out how to attach .css() to the individual letters._ - Not possible without putting each letter in its own HTML element, either in your markup like `<span>G</span><span>R</span>`..., or by modifying the HTML with JS to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jon Uleis is right, you cannot style individual characters. But you can style DOM elements, like `<span>`:

```js
var header = $('#header'),
    headerSpans = header.text()
                        .split("")
                        .map(function(char){
                           return $('<span>' + char + '</span>');
                        });
header.html(headerSpans);

headerSpans[9].css('color', 'red');
headerSpans[10].css('color', 'blue');
headerSpans[11].css('color', 'green');
headerSpans[12].css('color', 'orange');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">INTRO TO GRID</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the style of elements with JavaScript using **style object** which can be accessed from specific HTML element or from the head section of the document. Find more about style document [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp).

There are plenty of solutions for your problem but I tried to provide you one which is simple to understand.

**My solution:**

1. You need to get HTML element where you will store your text. (In my example it is div element which id is **root**)
2. Store every character of your text in one array. (In my example, name of array is **text**).
3. Loop through array of characters with forEach method.( More about forEach [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)).
4. Create new span element for every letter inside forEach method.
5. Wrap every character in text node and append it to created span.
6. Style every span however you want to. (If statement is used to limit styling only to the word "GRID").
7. Append created and styled span to the div element where text will be displayed.

**Solution code:**

```js
const div = document.getElementById(`root`); // div from HTML 

const text = `INTRO TO GRID`.split(``); // every character of your text stored in array

text.forEach((char, index) => {

  const node = document.createElement(`span`); // create new span element                
  const textnode = document.createTextNode(char);  // create character as text node for span element
  
  node.appendChild(textnode); // add text to span
  
  // if you want only to style characters only in the word `GRID`
  if(index >= text.length - `GRID`.length){
  
    // style the characters however you want to
    node.style.color = index % 2 === 0 ? `red` : `black`; // change color
    node.style.fontWeight = index % 2 !== 0 ? 900 : 1; // change font weight
  }
  
  div.appendChild(node); // add span (character) to the div element in HTML
});
```

```html
<div id="root">
  
</div>
```